# MNIST Dataset, difference of grid search and not, about accuracy

Tags: artificial-intelligence, svm, logistic-regression, mnist, grid-search

I study AI class and implement Datase MNIST. When I classify the data using grid search and not, SVM and Logistic Regression, it give me almost same accuracy. Is it possible? If it is right results, I want to know reason why it is almost same results. And if I choice one thing, what is correct option to me.  Plz explain to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which hyperparameters are you optimizing with the grid search? What range are you using? And what do you consider "almost the same" accuracy? Show us some code, please.

Comment: https://github.com/parkyechan/fall2019_AI/tree/master/Team_Project_1/ayj
This is my github source

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's way too much to get into for me. Can you produce a minimal example of some sort? See this help page on how to do that: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example